# JRE library System

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to add Jre Library System to my Project. For that I clicked the name of my project (`projet1`), then properties ---> java build path ---> Libraries and after I add Jre system library [jre8].

I even added the library, but it does not appear in my project. I want to have something like this:

[image: http://uploads.siteduzero.com/files/396001_397000/396174.png]

In my class path I got this

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.‌​launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.7" />
```

**How can I do that?**

Answer (score 0):

your .classpath file must have line
 `<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>`

Open navigator view and check .classpath file contents

If you are using another jdk ... u should see JRE NAME you added instead of JRE_CONTAINER

like

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/jdk1.6.0_27"/>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.  I found:                          <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.7"/>                               what's that mean

Comment: It means JRE named JavaSE-1.7 is added to your classpath.

Comment: You can check installed JRE's . You must have JRE named JavaSE-1.7 there. If not then you need to add it there